# Toast notifications doesn't navigate to the url if the app is in foreground and obscured by the lock screen

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, push-notification

I'm having problems with the toast notifications in Windows Phone. If the application is in background or dead, when I receive the notification with the url in the `wp:Param` and I tap on it, the app is opened in the specified screen.

The problem is when the application is in foreground and the screen is locked. Then I receive the toast notification but when I tap on it, the app is opened in the previous screen that it was before the device was locked.

Is there any way to prevent this?